# Echoing one or the other in PHP

Tags: php, echo

If I want to echo the value that's *not* blank, then I would do something of the sort

```
<?php echo $a ? $a : 'blank'; ?>
```

But I was wondering if you could use some syntax like

```
<?php echo $a or 'blank'; ?>
```

But this will echo `1` or `0`.

What I want it to do is emulate the first block of code. In other words, is there a short hand for the first block of code: `echo empty($a) ? $a : 'blank';`?

*This question inspired by the fact that you can write `$fp = fopen('file.txt') or die('bad file')`*

**Update**: I suppose I could do:

```
<?php
    or_echo($a, 'blank');

    function or_echo($arg1, $arg2) {
        if(!empty($arg1)) {
            echo $arg1; return;
        }
        else {
            echo $arg2; return;
        }
        return;
    }
?>
```

Comment: @stomo21 sorry, meant `!empty(...`. fixed.

Comment: I always wanted to do this in PHP, but it's not possible without doing an explicit check on that variable. Be glad that PHP is a loosely-typed language and so using `if` to check a variable is ["truthy" or "falsey"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (so will be false if the value is `null`, `undefined`, etc..). The `or` functionality you speak of works with `die()` or `exit()` functions because it doesn't actually set the variable, and stops further processing of the code, and the value to the left of the `or` is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t (at least without suppressing errors in some way). In most languages, especially dynamically-typed ones like PHP, you could do something along these lines:

```
echo $_GET['message'] || 'blank';
```

PHP forgoes this in the name of code clarity, of course.

Regarding your update, no, you can’t. Accessing `$_GET['message']` is a warning when `!array_key_exists('message', $_GET)`. However, this would work:

```
function get($key, $default) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : $default;
}

echo get('message', 'blank');
```

Comment: Revised. What I really meant was in a general case, `echo $a || 'blank'`, with the precondition that `$a` has been properly defined.

Comment: I’d still use a more generic function, so you could do `echo or_default($a, 'blank');`.

Answer (score 0):

This perhaps isn't short hand, but it uses the `or` operator to achieve the same thing.

```
$a = '';
//$a = 'hi';

$a or $a = 'blank';
echo $a;
```

---

One liner:

```
 <?php $a or $a = 'blank'; echo $a ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php echo isset($a) ?: 'blank'; ?>
```

This would be similar to `<?php echo $a ? $a : 'blank'; ?>`